# Query items user was mentioned in

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to query work items where a user was mentioned? I am able to receive 'hard-coded' results by querying for

**"History"-"Contains word"-"\@Username"**,

but I want a generic version, which works for all users. (Opposed to writing one query for every user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this by work item query directly just as starain mentioned. You can create a [custom hub](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-hub) or [custom widget](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget) by using [VSTS Extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview) to show these information in web portal.

Answer (score 40):

Use this predicate:

- Field: "ID"
- Operator: "In"
- Value: "@RecentMentions"

This automatically filters for work items, where *current user* has been *mentioned*.

I found it in predefined filter "Mentioned" in "Work Items" section. If you click on "Open in Queries" button, you will get a query with above filter. (This section can even remove the need for that query...)

**Note:** at present time, works only in VSTS.

Comment: Error says ID and @RecentMentions are a different data type, even with the "In" operator.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behaviour; it is still working for me. If I use an operator different than "In" it is said that @RecentMentions is an array and as soon as I write "@" default variables are shown for autocompletion. What environment are you using, TFS or DevOps?

Comment: In VS, apparently not supported there.  Works in DevOps.  My bad, didn't see the tag.  I'll remove my downvote but you have to make an edit.

Comment: This worked for me in Azure DevOps which is essentially SaaS VSTS

Answer (score 5):

```
https://{org}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_workitems/mentioned/
```

This would achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t achieve that through work item query directly, you could build a app to retrieve data through REST API (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql), change query text according different conditions (e.g. users)

Comment: Ok, but as far as I can see there is no way to integrate these into the visualstuioonline.com query interface/dashboards

Comment: As Eddie said that, you can create a VSTS extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this
Select Id,Title From WorkItems Where ID IN (@RecentMentions) order by [System.ChangedDate] desc

here is the reference for rest of the macro's available in ADO rest API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=azure-devops